# Joins are not giving the right answers

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

`1)select count(*) from LCL_RKM_AuditForm; **O/P : 868**`

`2)select count(*) from RKM_KnowledgeArticleManager; **O/P : 8511**`

```
3)select count(*) from 
LCL_RKM_AuditForm A
**right** outer join 
RKM_KnowledgeArticleManager B
on A.ARTICLE_ID=B.DocID; **O/P : 9216**

4)select count(*) from 
LCL_RKM_AuditForm A
**left** outer join 
RKM_KnowledgeArticleManager B
on A.ARTICLE_ID=B.DocID; **O/P : 1973**

5)select count(*) from 
LCL_RKM_AuditForm A,RKM_KnowledgeArticleManager B
**where** A.ARTICLE_ID=B.DocID; **O/P : 1973**
```

My understanding is that.,.

Left outer join will Displays all the values in A table and common values in B table.

Right outer join will Displays all the values in B table and common values in A table.

What does that Common Values refers to ? If its the **left** outer join which means it should give only **868** results right ? And if its **right** outer join which means it should give only **8511** results right ?

5th statement i have used **WHERE** clause which means it should give me only **868** entries right ?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are your ID field unique in either table? Looks like you're just getting multiple matches for some values.

Comment: Yes its not unique in either table. My requirement is to get all the rows from A table with 3 columns and respective value  from B table with 1 column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expected results appear to be based on the false assumption that there is a one-to-one mapping between rows in the two tables.

For a standard inner join (as in your last query), every matching combination of rows from the two tables is returned.  Since you are getting more results than there are rows in the first table, it must be true that a given row in the first table may have multiple matching rows in the second table.

For instance, if there is one row in table A with ArticleID = 1, and two rows in Table B with DocID = 1, then a join of the two tables on these fields will produce 2 rows.

When you change to an outer join, you will get at least the same number of rows as the inner join, and potentially more.  An outer join will return the same rows as the corresponding inner join; plus, for any row in the "inner" table that does not have any match in the "outer" table, it will return that one row, with NULL values for columns from the second table.

Your LEFT OUTER JOIN returns the same number of rows as the inner join; this implies that every row in table A has at least one matching row in table B.

Your RIGHT OUTER JOIN returns many more rows.  This implies that there are many rows in table B that have no matching row in table A.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dave. Now i have achieved my requirement by using the combination of two columns as below
>>select count(*) from 
LCL_RKM_AuditForm A
left outer join 
RKM_KnowledgeArticleManager B
on A.ARTICLE_ID=B.DocID and A.ARTICLE_VERSION = B.ARTICLEVERSION;